# How to make capturing group optional?

Tags: java, regex

**Input**

```
example("This is tes't")

example('This is the tes\"t')
```

**Ouput should be**

`This is tes't`

`This is the tes"t`

**Code**

```
 String text = "example(\"This is tes't\")";
//String text = "$.i18nMessage('This is the tes\"t\')";
final String quoteRegex = "example.*?(\".*?\")?('.*?')?";
        Matcher matcher0 = Pattern.compile(quoteRegex).matcher(text);
        while (matcher0.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher0.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher0.group(2));

        }
```

I see output as

```
null
null
```

Though when i use  regex `example.*?(\".*?\")` it returns `This is tes't` and when i use `example.*?('.*?')`  it returns
`This is the tes"t` but whn i combine both with `example.*?(\".*?\")?('.*?')?` it returns null . Why ?

Comment: Use `matcher0.matches()` if you plan to match the whole string. However, you are looking for something like [`example\\((([\"'])(?:(?!\\2).)*\\2)\\)`](https://regex101.com/r/qUX1gl/2)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to match here.  Can you show us sample input and the matches you want?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please see my update

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to know what the issue in my regex  as first and second capturing groups works fine independently but when i combine them and make them optional with `?` it does not work ?

Comment: Your regex matches [like this](https://regex101.com/r/W7zB2u/1). Either just `example`, or if quoted sting immediately follows, those a captured. It happens since all patterns at the end of the regex are optional. You might have at least tried [`(\".*?\"|'.*?')`](https://regex101.com/r/W7zB2u/2).

Comment: Also, `matcher0.find()` finds partial matches. If you use `matches()`, you won't get the problem, but you won't get the captures either, since the `.*?` will [grab all the text](https://regex101.com/r/jqR86c/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*?(\".*?\")?('.*?')?` subpattern sequence at the end of your regex can match an empty string (all 3 parts are quantified with `*` / `*?` that match 0 or more chars). After matcing `example`, the `.*?` is skipped at first, and is only expanded once the subsequent subpatterns do not match. However, they both match an empty string before `(`, thus, you only have `example` in `matcher0.group(0)`.

Use either an alternation that makes group 1 obligatory ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/W7zB2u/2)):

```
Pattern.compile("example.*?(\".*?\"|'.*?')"
```

Or a variant with a tempered greedy token ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/qUX1gl/3)) that allows to get rid of the alternation:

```
Pattern.compile("example.*?(([\"'])(?:(?!\\2).)*\\2)"
```

Or, better, support escaped sequences ([another demo](https://regex101.com/r/qUX1gl/4)):

```
Pattern.compile("example.*?(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*')"
```

In all 3 examples, you only need to access Group 1. If there can only be `(` between `example` and `"` or `'`, you should replace `.*?` with `\(` since it will make matching safer. Although, it is never too safe to use a regex to match string literals (at least, with one regex).